# Upload files to a directory in Google Drive

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to set up a form that will upload files into a specific directory of my google drive, instead of the home directory.

I found a script that works to upload files and it works, though i would prefer that it goes into a different folder.

Currently files will go into "/"
How would I make files go to "/new/property/uploads/"?

Google Script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Uploads";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

Form Script:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Get the folder trough driveApp and save it there, really simple.

1. Create the folder manually, if you need dinamically there are a few more steps
2. Get the ID -> navigate in the browser and open the folder, the last digits after the last "/" are the folder's ID
3. Use the driveApp function [getFolderById(String)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String)) to select thy folder Eg. `folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(ID)`

The check for the folder is pointless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where the folder you want doesn't exist, and you want to create a new tree of subfolders, you need to create a new folder in the folder.  The folder class has a `createFolder()` method.  The DriveApp class also has a `createFolder()` method, but that puts a new folder into the main Drive root.  So, both DriveApp and Folder have a `createFolder()` method.  The key is to first get a reference to the folder that you want to use `createFolder()` on to create a new folder as a sub folder.

```
function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Uploads";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      var firstLevelFolder = DriveApp.createFolder("new");
      var secondLevelFolder = firstLevelFolder.createFolder("property");
      var folder = secondLevelFolder.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('err: ' + error.toString());
    return error.toString();
  }

}
```